Why LibreOffice on Ubuntu does not see my C drive?
I have installed the latest version of LO on the latest version of Ubuntu.  I can only see and save on documents folder.  LO does not see C drive.  While on Ubuntu I can see this C drive in "FILES", but not in LO.
Any idea how to fix this?
thanks in advance

Is the LO a Snap app?

Is the Ubuntu install on Windows with WSL? Or is this a dual-boot machine? I'm not sure of any other situations where you'd have a C: drive accessible -- maybe over a network or running a virtual machine? So assume it's dual-boot: how is your (C:)drive's partition mounted? That should answer the question of where to look for it in the file manager or app of your choice.  Assuming again that the drive/partition IS mouinted, right? Open a terminal and try the 'mount | sort' commands: that will help answer some of these questions!

I do not think it is the C drive it looks like the C drive due to what the OP sees in the directory. I access the Windows directories on my dual boot machine from the Ubuntu OS all the time.

"latest version" becomes meaningless over time, while something like loffice --version and lsb_release -a would be more precise, accurate, and will last forever in your edited Question.  Please [edit] your Question to add information.  Do not reply via Add Comment.

There is no C drive in Linux. There are /, /home etc.

Since I posted the question only an hour ago I doubt if a new version of anything has been released, hence at least to me the latest version seem to be self explanatory.  Also yes Ubuntu is installed on a laptop that originally had Windows 11 and is dual boot now.

What's a "C Drive" in linux?

Here I assume that by "C Drive" you are referring to Ubuntu's root partition.

The snap version of libreoffice does not see many partitions due to lack of permissions. Replace it with the apt version (which, being a native package, will not have these issues).
Open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one
sudo snap remove libreoffice
sudo apt install libreoffice


Hi thanks for instruction but I got one error after each code.  I got Libreoffice is not installed and something like package not found.  Jesusblooming christ, I had not typed any code anywhere since 38 years ago in SUN. This Ubuntu thing is high level technology, no wonder its catching on like wild fire :)

Please edit the question and post the error message. Without it, we cannot help. Also, try sudo apt update followed by sudo apt install libreoffice

why do you want me to edit the question? what is missing?

When I log into win11 I have drive C and other drives and file manager can take care of that.  When I log into Ubuntu I see an icon for files with the title SSD.  I click on I see the C drive and al the subfolders.  ubuntu can see my C drive.

THEN I open Libreoffice and try to open a file from C drive.   I see documents, downloads and at the botom is OTHER LOCATIONS.  Clicking on it shows only COMPUTER on the right side and clicking on that shows me a lot of folders such as writable, var, usr, tmp,........   So what happened to my C drive and its subfolders?  This problem is from Libreoffice side not ubuntu.  Question is how can it be fixed?

Please edit the question and post some screenshots of the problem. Also, you said there was some error message while installing Libreoffice. We need the full error message.

From Ubuntu, you need to look for directories and files in the directory where the partition is mounted, usually by default it is in /media/user/xxxxxx
